# Odoo module can't find python lib

Tags: python, ubuntu, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to install an odoo module "[auth_signup_verify_email](https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/10.0/auth_signup_verify_email)"
but when I click on install it gives an error:

`Unable to install module "auth_signup_verify_email" because an external dependency is not met: No module named validate_email`

I figured it is a missing python lib and installed the `validate_email` lib using the command `pip install validate_email` and restarted the odoo service..

But still the same issue is there.. I found out that the lib is installed on this path: `$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` I not sure if this is the path where odoo is looking for lib..

Another possible reason is that PYTHONPATH in odoo can be wrong, but I don't know how to check for that or how to change it..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

solved by moving the installed lib from `.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to `/usr/lib/python2.7/`